# How can i add value in Option Select?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a textarea text "ez.aaaa.value" i want to typing a text and when i select option , redirect automatically to google.com/search?tbm=isch&q= + ((value textarea))

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWiVp.png)

Example :

```
........
<option value="href='http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=' + ez.aaaa.value">google search</option>
........
```

Comment: What is this select for??

Comment: Explain your question

Comment: Have you tried `$( "#myselect option:selected" ).text(); (or val())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: Are you looking to get the value of the selected item or are you trying to dynamically set the value inside of a select by selecting the option programmatically? Or are you trying to dynamically add another option to your select?

Comment: @EugineJoseph .. i have a textarea text "ez.aaaa.value" i want to type a text and when i select option , redirect automatically to http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q= + ((value textarea))

Comment: @MoxetKhan Khan .. i have a textarea text "ez.aaaa.value" i want to type a text and when i select option , redirect automatically to http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q= + ((value textarea))

Comment: @creativekinetix .. i have a textarea text "ez.aaaa.value" i want to type a text and when i select option , redirect automatically to http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q= + ((value textarea))

Comment: Ok. Then the selected one is the correct answer. Plus you need to add the encodeURIComponent to the query.value. so that, the spaces and the other special characters will be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

the `location.href` is what you would use to link out.

`this` refers to the select and `selectedIndex` returns the number of the selected option.

```js
var sel = document.getElementById('mysel'),
    query = document.getElementById('myquery');

sel.addEventListener('change' , function() {
  console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + query.value);
  
  // this would be how to link below
  // location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + query.value;
});
```

```html
<input type='text' id="myquery">
<select id="mysel">
  <option>SELECT ONE</option>
  <option value="http://google.com?q=">google</option>
  <option value="http://bing.com?q=">bing</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Remove the // in front of the `location.href` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Add  `select` with ID outside of your `option` and then try this way

**JS**

```
var e = document.getElementById("select-menu");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
console.log(strUser);
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="select-menu">
<option value="href='http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=' + ez.aaaa.value">google search 1</option>
<option value="href='http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=' + ez.aaaa.value" selected="selected">google search 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks , how can i auto redirect  link to "href='http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=' + ez.aaaa.value "

Comment: @moon90 Use `window.location = strUser;`  to redirect in same tab.

Comment: 1) Use Javascript event onchange on the <select> to get the event.
2) For redirection use window.location.href = selectedValue;